# Authenticate to Yammer in c# console application

Tags: c#, yammer

I am using the NuGet Yammer API and I am trying to simply authenticate and display the token as a test.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get it working. I am new to this but there is no documentation on the NuGet Yammer API and it will be a console application. All the examples and documentation on the Yammer developers page show doing this from a web based appication.

My code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myConfig = new ClientConfigurationContainer
    {

        ClientCode = null,
        ClientId = "CODEHERE",
        ClientSecret = "CODEHERE"
    };
    var myYammer = new YammerClient(myConfig);
    var test = myYammer.GetToken();
    Console.WriteLine("Token" + test);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Just in case: have you put your ClientId and ClientSecret into your code? :)

Comment: Yes lol ... I removed them to post on here :)

Comment: There is no error, it just doesn't display any token... I just get the word "Token" in my console window which displayed

Comment: Well after I stop the application I get 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in RestSharp.dll but this could just be because I ended the application?

Comment: What is happening is that the API wrapper is not accounting for some value in the JSON response from Yammer. You need to look at the InnerException of the SerializationException. When you use static languages like C# you need to take special account of how you handle null cases in the JSON, or this problem will crop up.

Answer (score 3):

It's an [OAuth authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth), you must interact with Yammer OAuth webpage to obtain a token.

You should look in the asp.net mvc example in sources on [**Github**](https://github.com/RaynaldM/Yammer.SimpleAPI).

In the HomeController.cs :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var myConfig = new ClientConfigurationContainer
        {
            ClientCode = null,
            ClientId = model.ClientId,
            ClientSecret = model.ClientSecret,
            RedirectUri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + Url.Action("AuthCode")
        };

        var myYammer = new YammerClient(myConfig);

        // Obtain the URL of Yammer Authorisation Page
        var url = myYammer.GetLoginLinkUri();

        this.TempData["YammerConfig"] = myConfig;

        // Jump to the url page
        return Redirect(url);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

And Yammer redirect you here:

```
public ActionResult AuthCode(String code)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
    {
        var myConfig = this.TempData["YammerConfig"] as ClientConfigurationContainer;
        myConfig.ClientCode = code;
        var myYammer = new YammerClient(myConfig);
        // var yammerToken = myYammer.GetToken();
        // var l = myYammer.GetUsers();
        // var t= myYammer.GetImpersonateTokens();
        // var i = myYammer.SendInvitation("test@test.fr");
        // var m = myYammer.PostMessage("A test from here", 0, "Event");
        return View(myYammer.GetUserInfo());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the API. Inside YammerClient.cs in GetAccessToken() it needs to pass false into use body as it is GET command and this is failing.

Answer (score 2):

The person who wrote the API also wrote an article on how to use it, which is here:

http://fullsaas.blogspot.fr/2013/05/a-simple-net-wrapper-of-yammer-api.html

This may also be useful:

https://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2013/10/05/using-the-yammer-api-in-a-net-client-application.aspx